# use mailgun api and send email with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, python, ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I am trying to use [mailgun.com](http://mailgun.com) for sending emails. But it happened that I need to send it with js (cause sometimes I built websites with rubyonrails, sometimes with python. And now I need to built a simple landing page with mail sending.
And hosting  (which is free ad suits me   only supports php which I don't know)
So I decided to use js and obfuscate this code and paste it somewhere in somelibrary.So no one will ever find my secret key)
Can someone help with translating some of this examples  into js code?

This is python example:

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
        auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
              "to": ["bar@example.com", "YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME"],
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

This is c# example

```
public static IRestResponse SendSimpleMessage() {
       RestClient client = new RestClient();
       client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
       client.Authenticator =
               new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                          "YOUR_API_KEY");
       RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
       request.AddParameter("domain",
                            "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
       request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
       request.AddParameter("from", "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>");
       request.AddParameter("to", "bar@example.com");
       request.AddParameter("to", "YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME");
       request.AddParameter("subject", "Hello");
       request.AddParameter("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!");
       request.Method = Method.POST;
       return client.Execute(request);
}
```

This is php example

```
# Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('YOUR_API_KEY');
$domain = "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME";

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
    'to'      => 'Baz <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
    'subject' => 'Hello',
    'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
));
```

This is rails example:

```
def send_simple_message
  RestClient.post "https://api:YOUR_API_KEY"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
  :from => "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
  :to => "bar@example.com, YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME",
  :subject => "Hello",
  :text => "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscated code just slows down the naughty coder who is trying to mess up, its not a perfect layer of security. Since you say your host supports php use the php code. all you have to do is send a post request to the php script
example code considering you are sending using jQuery library for javascript

```
    <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

if(isset($_POST['variable1']) && isset($_POST['variable2']))
{
$msg = $_POST['variable1']." ".$_POST['variable1'];
$mgClient = new Mailgun('key');
$domain = "your domain";
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'from adress',
    'to'      => 'to adress',
    'subject' => 'some subject',
    'html'    => $msg
));
$result = objectToArray($result);
echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

jquery code to send post request

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("mailer.php",
    {
        variable1: "Donald Duck",
        variable2: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The above code sends a post request to your php file, where the php file validates if it contains the variables 1 and 2 and continues with the execution

Comment: require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
Do I need to configure something else? like install mailgun or something like this?

Comment: @user2950593 please download the official php sdk from the mailgun site and extract the vendoer folder onto your server

Comment: @user2950593 here is the link https://9f67cbbd1116d8afb399-7760483f5d1e5f28c2d253278a2a5045.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/mailgun-php-1.7.2.zip